# Max Number of span sessions

Tags: cisco, mirror

I'm trying to find a command that will show me the max number of span sessions i can have on a single switch, but so far i havent been able to find it.

Is there any show command that does this??

Comment: I think you need to check the documentation for the switch model and software version it is running to find that out. You could suggest such a command to Cisco to see if it can be included in future releases.

Comment: Apparently, the 45xx with more recent IOS versions can do six SPAN sessions. This sounds like what I understood. I'm not sure why anyone would want to use that number of SPAN sessions. SPAN is really designed as a troubleshooting tool that is set up temporarily, not something that will be used as a permanent sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a command that will show me the number of spans sessions on a switch.
After you enter into config mode, enter in the command `monitor session ?` to get the number of a span sessions on that switch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of any command that shows the maximum number of SPAN sessions allowed (on a Cisco switch), although I've also never seen more than two allowed.

You can see how many SPAN sessions are configured by the command

```
show monitor
```

Comment: I think the 45xx switches allow more than two. It's still a relatively small number.

Comment: I found a table: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-6500-series-switches/10570-41.html#anc43